# No puedo agregar un origen remoto de mis archivos a origin

Tags: git, github

**RESUELTO! Agregué la resolución abajo, como respuesta.**

Estoy aprendiendo Git y GitHub (por eso tambien me cuesta explicar lo que quiero decir)

El objetivo, segun el curso que estoy haciendo, es tener en mi carpeta de la notebook el archivo README.md que tengo en GitHub.

Estoy en GitBash. En mi carpeta, en mi proyecto, y en la rama (master).
Ya llegué al punto en el que tengo un origin para hacer (fetch) y un origin para hacer (push).
Tambien ejecuté "git push origin master", me abrió la ventana para ingresar usuario y contraseña de GitHub, ahí todo bien.

Hago "git pull origin master" para traerl el origin a mi rama master, pero a  diferencia del profesor, a mi sólo me figura la rama:

- branch   master  →FETCH_HEAD

Al profesor, a diferencia de a mi, también le figura:

*[new branch]  master → origin/master

Luego el profesor ejecuta el siguiente comando:
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories

y logra hacer el merge con la rama master del proyeto. Al ejecutar "ls -al" se puede ver que le trajo el archivo "README.md"

Alguien sabría decirme qué puede ser lo que me está fallando?
Debido a que lo intente varias veces ya lo único que me dice cuando lo trato de volver a hacer es "everything up to date"

Secuencia de comandos que hice:

```
git remote add origin *****
```

(siendo **** la URL que copié de mi proyecto en GitHub

```
git remote
```

me aparece "origin"

```
git remote -v
```

Me muestra un origin para hacer fetch y otro para push

```
git push origin master
```

Me salta la ventana de GitHub que me pide usuario y contraseña.
Ahora, a mi profesor le saló error, a mi no. Y lo que hizo fue trar el master con

```
git pull origin master
```

Y con eso le salió un warning. Entonces lo forzó con:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Explicó que con ésto forzaba la fusion entre lo que hay en el origen con la rama que tengo en el local (master).

En éste punto ya le permite hacer el merge con la rama master, lo lleva al vim y  le da enter. Pero yo no pude llegar ahí. No logro que los archivos de mi computadora (todo mi proyecto) aparezca en el proyecto en GitHub ni que la carpeta README que hice en GitHub aparezca en mi proyecto en mi computadora.

Comment: Creo que seria una buena idea que colocaras la secuencia de comandos y acciones que fuiste ejecutando para tener una idea clara de tu situación. En todo caso, si la idea es ejecutar un `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`, no veo por qué harías un push _antes_ de dicho merge (ya que con eso borrarías lo que haya en el remoto.... bueno, si usas `--force` en el push).

Comment: en realidad la idea es simplemente hacer un merge con la rama master de mi proyecto de GItHub. Tengo entendido que con "Git push origin master" hubiera bastado. No lo sé porque ahí al profesor (luego de ingresar usuario y contraseña)  le apareció un error. Algo de "las actualizaciones fueron rechazadas porque el remoto contiene trabajo que no tengo localmente". Explicó que es porque ahora el remoto es el master. Entonces hizo "git pull origin master" y luego "git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories" y ahí si pudo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví!
(No estoy segura como tengo que proceder en este caso en Stack Overflow, si tengo que responder mi propia pregunta como estoy haciendo, editar la pregunta que hice, o qué. Si alguien me lo quiere aclarar se los agradezco)

Resulta que el curso que estoy siguiendo es viejo, y en un momento, unos años despues, GitHub cambió su rama por defecto de "main" a "master".
Lo que tuve que hacer para que funcione es editar el nombre de esa rama y renombrarla "master".

Voy a poner la explicacion que escribió una chica en esa pagina del curso:
Si a ustedes no les sale el mensaje de que se tiene que traer los cambios y al intentar hacer el pull les dice que todo esta actualizado es porque GitHub cambió su rama por defecto a "main" y nosotros estamos trabajando con la rama master, por lo tanto GitHub lo estaba tomando como un pull request (porque son diferentes ramas). Para seguir esta clase deben borrar el repositorio en GitHub (si ya lo tenian creado) y configurar su rama por defecto como master.

Comment: Y escribir tu propia respuesta, si la conseguiste, es válido.

Answer (score 1):

la manera más sana de proceder es

```
 git clone https://github.com/<usuario>/<proyecto>
```

Se crea una carpeta llamada como el proyecto, y ya está en la rama master con README.md y todo.

Otro escenario: Supongamos que en tu situación actual creaste y commiteaste otros archivos. No tienes README.md en tu local, ni los nuevos archivos en el remoto.

El primer commit en cada uno es distinto y git no puede computar los cambios via merge. Lo mismo podrían ser dos proyectos distintos y provocar un desaste. Pero si realmente quieres forzar ese "merge", puedes usar el `--allow-unrelated-stories`.

Si nos apegamos al objetivo que nos cuentas, traer archivo(s) o carpetas del remoto sin pedirle a git que los compagine, es mucho más fácil. Te traes el remoto con fetch. Queda en tu local como ref, pero no intenta mergear.

```
git fetch --all
```

Ahora usas `checkout` sobre la rama que el fetch te acaba de traer.

```
git checkout origin/master README.md
```

Si tienes un README.md ten en consideración que lo sobreescribirá, sin mergear. No puedes mergear un archivo individual sin hacer un jutsu prohibido que mejor ni aprender. (pero véanlo [bajo su propia responsabilidad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214906/how-do-i-merge-a-sub-directory-in-git))

Comment: Definitivamente lo mas sencillo es clonar, pero como está siguiendo instrucciones de un profesor (que por lo visto le gusta que las cosas sean complicadas), supongo que debería seguir la receta... por lo menos hasta que entienda los conceptos (es decir, mas o menos hasta que estar en `detached HEAD` no mande escalofríos por la espalda).

Comment: `subtree split` es mi copiloto

Comment: Poca experiencia con subtrees o modules por mi lado :-O Algún día.

Comment: Era una broma. Yo intenté usarlo para "desacoplar" las imágenes de un wordpress gigante a otro repo. Pero a diferencia de submodules, acá tu copia local no se limita a reportar el HEAD. Seguí recorriendo 64GB de fotos cada vez que cambiaba de directorio. Conclusión: symlink, a lo bestia

Answer (score 1):

En la secuencia de comandos que pusiste veo un pequeño error. La forma de lograr unir ambas ramas (tu master local y el origin/master) es, como probablememte hizo tu profesor:

```
git fetch origin # actualiza la info de lo que hay en el remoto, no hace nada sobre ninguna de tus ramas locales
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/master
```

Eso logra juntar ambas ramas y entonces podrías hacer:

```
git push origin @ #empuja la rama actual, master, al remoto origin
```

Si quieres que git recuerde la relación entre ambas ramas, coloca un `-u` como opción al push y entonces podrías decir `git pull` o `git push` al estar sobre master para que haga las operaciones respectivas contra origin/master.

Comment: Siento que con ésto me acerqué.. con ese comando "git fetch origin" me apareció la nueva rama ( [new branch] master → origin/master ) pero no pude lograr que vuelva a aparecer y sigo sin poder fusionar lo que hay en GitHub (que es solo el README) con la rama que hay en local. El README sigue sin aparecer en mis carpeta y los archivos siguen sin subirse a GitHub...

Comment: Si el fetch la vio, ya la puedes usar.... por ejemplo, `git log origin/master` te debe mostrar su historia. Luego un `git merge` (con todo lo que le puse en la receta) te debe permitir mezclarla con lo que tienes. Si no es así, pon la salida del `git merge` en un comentario o como info de la pregunta a ver cual puede ser el problema.

Comment: con el "git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/master"  me indica "Already up to date" y con el "git push origin @" me dice "Everything up to date". Pareciera que ya esta todo hecho, pero sigue sin aparecer mi proyecto (El que tengo en mi compu) en mi repositorio GitHub, ni el README.md en la carpeta de mi proyecto.

Comment: Como se ve la historia con `git log --all --oneline --graph`? Y el archivo sale listado con `git ls-tree -r origin/master`?

Comment: ya encontré la respuesta, gracias! el profesor hacia los ejercicios teniendo en cuenta que la rama de GitHub era "master", pero recientemente GitHub cambió el nombre por default a "main". Solo tuve que volverla a cambiar a "master" y ahí puede hacerlo, no tenia idea. Muchas gracias igual por toda la ayuda!

Comment: 'Celente! Mucha suerte en el aprendizaje! Y pacieeeeeencia, mucha paciencia.

Comment: jajaj muchisimas gracias!!